# Setup environment for android sdk to run cocos2d sample programs.

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I want to install cocos2d to develop game in android .. so can anyone help me how to install that on android sdk ?

Please Suggest me steps to install it....

if any other tool is available for android development then please suggest me ..

Thanks ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After downloading cocos2d from the link mentioned in above answer you need to do the following to integrate cocos2d in you project:

- Import cocos2d in workspace.
- Go to project properties and mark cocos2d as library.
- Create now your project and add cocos2d library in project
  properties.
- If you are using box2d maybe you had to add .so to your project like
  cocos(libs/...).

Now you can write your game.
Also you can include all sources into your project, and no need in any cocos2d jar.
The above steps are mentioned at http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android-1/wiki/Using

Answer (score 6):

ya you can install cocos2d in android.....

First you download the cocos2d jar from

http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android-1/downloads/detail?name=cocos2d-android.jar&can=2&q=

Sample code is available in

https://github.com/ZhouWeikuan/cocos2d

Comment: Thanks soorya for your efforts... I download the jar file .. now what to do ?

Comment: I download jar file, now what to do ?